# How can I increase Terraria's default resolution?

Tags: terraria

I'd like to increase the default resolution because it's very small. There's nothing in the options menu, and I checked the folders where it is installed and didn't find any sort of options.ini file that I could hand edit.

Is there any way to do this? I run a dual monitor setup and at the current resolution, it makes my second monitor practically useless.

Comment: Even at 1280x1024 fullscreen, the resolution is horrible. And I don't mean Minecraft blocky; literally poor.

Comment: It would be nice if you could at least resize the window that it gives you, like in Minecraft

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UPDATE: 1.0.3

The game window is now resizeable and you can select your resolution while in full screen mode. WooT!

- Also after setting fullscreen resolution, you can simple alt+enter it back to a window while retaining your resolution.

Answer (score 6):

As reported by [Terraria 1.0.3 changelog](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/1-0-3-change-log.19653/) it is now possible to change resolution. Window can also be re-sized when playing in windows mode. Great news!

> - The game window is now re-sizable while in windowed mode.
> - Full-screen resolution can now be changed in the options menu.