# How can I use very high resolutions like 2560x1440 in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

My monitor has a native resolution of 2560x1440, and I'd like to use the full resolution in Terraria. Unfortunately the game only allows resolutions up to 1920x1200 to be set from the video menu.

I assume the resolution is set somewhere in a config file, but the main Terraria config file seems to be binary, so I couldn't easily find the place where the resolution is stored.

Is there any way, official or not, to set the resolution to something higher than 1920x1200?

Comment: I was about to flag it as duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22484/how-can-i-increase-terrarias-default-resolution, but considering the answer there, I wonder if it really is...

Comment: Regardless of the answers, it is still a duplicate.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft No, the old questions refers to the time before the resolution was changeable at all. This is a separate problem, the old question can be fully answered now by "go to the video menu", my question not.

Comment: Does setting Terraria to windowed and then maximizing it not work?

Comment: @SaintWacko That doesn't increase the resolution for me

Comment: @MadScientist Hm, very odd. That's what has always worked for me. Kinda annoying on larger screens, because it makes everything tiny.

Answer (score 5):

The game has a maximum resolution of 1920 by 1200 hardcoded into the game executable. Some mods, such as [this one](http://romsteady.blogspot.fi/2013/11/romterraria-3-preview-release-incoming.html), supposedly let you bypass this limit. (I could not test it as my screen resolutions don't go high enough.)

Comment: I wrote RomTerraria.  I currently support up to 4096x4096.  To get the resolution that high, I had to do a runtime patch for XNA to override a limitation in the maximum size of textures and render targets, but it does work.

Comment: @RomSteady Any idea if this will work with the latest terraria update (1.3)?

Comment: @Seiyria, I just uploaded a version for 1.3.0.2+ here. http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2015/06/romterraria-4-released.html

Answer (score 1):

Terraria is made in the XNA framework. It has been programmed to the various screen size in the menu, and these variables are called by the `Console.Buffer`. To answer your question, the only two ways of doing this is to either change the code so it sets the height, width and resolution to your desire (which is not possible since it isn't open source). Or edit the binary file.

However, it is important to note that, that Terraria 2 is promised to be fully customizable and will probably solve such problems.

Comment: Terraria 2 will be a different game (not the next version of this game), so what it will/won't do isn't relevant to playing Terraria.

Comment: Edit the binary file **how**? This provides no actionable information.

Comment: @kotekzot I believe that by binary file he means the actual game executable. The whole point of this answer is that this can't be feasibly done.

Comment: @badp binary patches are hard, not impossible.

Comment: @badp No, it's a configuration file in some binary format. There was a tool to change the resolution at some point by manipulation of the binary config file, but that is no longer available.

Comment: @MadScientist Even modifying that binary config wouldn't let you go any higher than 1920x1200.